# Nginx the page you are looking for is not found . Reverse proxy error

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a small nginx server setup that forwards the request starting with /api to a specific port on the localhost

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            # proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_forwarded_for;
     }
```

}

I hosted this in my ec2 and it shows the nginx page on the ec2 public ipv4 address. But When i go to the /api route it shows The page you are looking for is not found. My app is running fine in port 8080 . I tested that by going to the specific port on the ip adress like  http:myip:8080/some-other-route  and it gave me response